# External USB device interface with Xilinx Atlys board

Tags: usb, hardware, fpga, xilinx

I'm trying to interface the Mindwave (http://store.neurosky.com/products/mindwave-1) with my Altys board, through the USB UART port. The dongle I'm trying to connect is basically a wireless reciever that outputs serial data stream on the USB connection. I'm trying to read in this serial stream on the FPGA.

The problem I'm seeing is that when I try to Chipscope the UartRx pin (A16), I see no activity on it even though the dongle is supposed to send 0xAA in standby mode.

Since the FPGA does not power the dongle, I have it connected to an external power USB hub and then connect the hub to the FPGA. However I don't see any activity.

Do I need to convert the signals to another level, or invert them? I thought the EXAR chip takes care of it.

Comment: This is more an embedded hardware question, not a programming question. Perhaps your question is better suited for http://electronics.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try swapping RX and TX?

Did you have acces to a scope? To check you can repeatly send 'U's (0x55) and look with a scope to see which line is RX and which is TX. You can also check the speed of the interface with this method.